# MySQL query array doesn't get populated when called with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm using ajax to return the results of a sql query on a WordPress site. Basically, there are two queries and I am displaying the results of the second query. The first query gets a list of posts that contain a certain custom field. The second query looks through those posts and lists out the posts that have another custom field associated with them. Right now, if I don't use ajax and just add this to my page template, everything works.

```
<?php
    $post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'Make' AND meta_value='Chevrolet'" );
    // now get the food names
    $stocktypes = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'Model' AND post_id IN (". implode(',', array_map('absint', $post_ids) ) .")" );


    if ($stocktypes) {
        foreach ($stocktypes as $stocktype) {
            echo "<option value=\"" . $stocktype . "\">" . $stocktype . "</option>";
        }
    }
?>
```

The problem comes when I add that to a separate file and call it with ajax. Here is the contents of my ajax file:

```
<?php

    $models = $_GET['Make'];

    $post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'Make' AND meta_value= %s", $models );

    $stocktypes = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'Model' AND post_id IN (". implode(',', array_map('absint', $post_ids) ) .")" );


    if ($stocktypes) {
        foreach ($stocktypes as $stocktype) {
            echo "<option value=\"" . $stocktype . "\">" . $stocktype . "</option>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is my ajax call:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#make").change(function() {
            $.ajax({ 
                url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/getModel.php", 
                data: { Make: $(this).val() },
                dataType: "html",
                type: "GET", 
                success: function(data){ 
                    $("#model").html(data); 
                } 

            }); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

The ajax call is working fine because I can echo the results of $models = $_GET['Make'];

By using `print_r(array_values($post_ids));`, I found that the $post_ids array of the first query isn't being populated in my ajax file. The only thing I could think of is that wp-load.php (which allows for the use of WordPress functions) wasn't being loaded but that's not the problem.

Comment: Can you echo out your generated SQL query? Does it look like it should? Does it work when you run it directly in the database?

Comment: Yes, if I add the query to my main page file (not using ajax) than I can run print_r(array_values($post_ids)); and get the array data.

Comment: Make sure you specify the type in `$.ajax` so that jquery doesn't have to guess at what you want to do. `type: "GET"`

Comment: I added type: "GET" but it's still not working.

Comment: @user715564 - you'll need to check the in the page you're calling, though. Either the parameter isn't being passed correctly, or the SQL you're generating isn't working right. You need to make sure that the SQL inside your AJAX file is correct.

Comment: Right, I believe the sql in the page i'm calling is wrong. If I run echo $post_ids the value is "array" but the array is empty. I'm confused because I know the $models variable is being populated. To call the $models variable in the query do I not use %s?

Comment: @user715564 - Instead of passing your SQL directly into `$wpdb`, try echoing it, so you can read it in the JSON response. Or you can try writing it to a log file, if that's going to be easier.

Comment: @user715564 - I don't actually pass parameters that way, so I can't so for sure. But you might need to make sure that there are quotes around what you're passing - I don't know if they're added for you when you create the query that way?

Comment: Actually, I just replaced meta_value= %s with meta_value= $models and it worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user715564 - I'm glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the first query. While I was using `meta_value= %s`, I should have been using `meta_value= $models`

Also, as pointed out by Kevin B, I added `type: "GET"` to my ajax call.